# Utilizando Django Bootstrap Modal Form, al usar ValidationError en el form, el error no se muestra en la ventana modal

Tags: bootstrap, django, formularios, modal

Soy nuevo en Django, y estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación. Uso Django 3.1.6, y uso django_bootstrap_modal_forms 2.0.1 para abrir ventanas modales.
Tengo una página, donde muestro información sobre pedidos realizados por un empleado. Desde allí, cada empleado puede gestionar los pedidos realizados, y hacer nuevas solicitudes. Es intención que cada una de estas acciones se muestren en una ventana modal. Las validaciones sencillas de cada formulario (campo vacío, por ejemplo) se hacen correctamente, y se muestran en la ventana modal. El problema lo tengo cuando intento validar si se duplica una solicitud para una determinada fecha. Esta verificación, sólo se hace  para ciertos tipos de pedidos, por ello la realizo en el *clean* del formulario llamando a ValidationError.

```
# views.py
class homeAgente3(ListView):
    model=Permiso
    template_name = 'gestionPermisos/index_demo_modal.html'
    context_object_name = 'permisos'
    
    def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)
        usuario = self.request.user.id
        return qs.filter(perUsuario__exact=usuario,perFechaArchivado__isnull=True,perEliminadoSolicitante__isnull=True) 

class PermisoTCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'gestionPermisos/permiso_edit_view2.html'
    form_class = PermisoModalForm
    success_message = 'El Permiso ha sido creado.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('homeAgente3')
    
    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.perUsuario = self.request.user
        form.instance.perFechaHora = datetime.now()
        tpermiso = TipoPermiso.objects.get(tperId=self.kwargs['tpermiso'])
        form.instance.perTPermiso = tpermiso 
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        idtp = self.kwargs['tpermiso']
        tpermiso = TipoPermiso.objects.get(tperId=idtp)
        context['titulo'] = 'Permiso %s' % tpermiso.tperDescripcion
        return context
```

El formulario

```
# forms.py
 class PermisoModalForm(BSModalModelForm):
    perMotivo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":5,"cols":20}),label='Motivo',required=True)
    perHoraIngreso = forms.TimeField(label='Hora Ingreso')
    perIdpermiso = forms.HiddenInput()
    class Meta:
        model=Permiso
        fields = ['perMotivo','perHoraIngreso','perIdpermiso']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        hoy = datetime.today()
        perIdEdit = self.instance.perIdpermiso  # Id de permiso si está editando
        # Validando si fue solicitado un permiso similar o no, que no haya sido eliminado
        try:
            permisocopy = Permiso.objects.get(perFechaHora__date=hoy,perTPermiso=tpermiso,perEliminadoSolicitante__isnull=True)
            perId = permisocopy.perIdpermiso
        except ObjectDoesNotExist: 
            permisocopy = None
        print('+++ ',permisocopy)
        if permisocopy is not None and perId != perIdEdit: 
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                message=format_html('Ya existe registrado un permiso similar.'),
                code='Invalido')
        return cleaned_data
```

El archivo urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('homeAgente3/', views.homeAgente3.as_view(), name='homeAgente3'),
    path('newT/<int:tpermiso>/',views.PermisoTCreateView.as_view(),name='newT'),
]
```

Como comentaba, el modal se muestra bien cuando lo llamo directamente desde un botón de la página "homeAgente3", y al hacer las validaciones sencillas. Aquí debajo el html:
index_demo_modal.html

```
{% extends 'gestionPermisos/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  {% include "gestionPermisos/_modal.html" %}

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h4>
          <strong>Demo Uso Bootstrap Modal Form</strong>
        </h4>
        <p>Crear, Modificar y Eliminar en Bootstrap modal.</p>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 mb-3">
            <button id="create-permiso-sync" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">
              <span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>Crear permiso
            </button>
           </div>
          <div class="col-12 mb-3">
          {% if 'type' in request.GET %}
            <p class="filtered-books">Filtered books.</p>
          {% endif %}
          {% include "gestionPermisos/_permisos_table.html" %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}

  {% block body_script %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {


          // Crear permiso synchronous
          function crearPermisoSyncModalForm() {
            $("#create-permiso-sync").modalForm({
                formURL: "{% url 'newT' tpermiso=1 %}",
                modalID: "#create-modal"
            });
          }
          crearPermisoSyncModalForm();

          // Create book asynchronous button
          // message
          var asyncSuccessMessageCreate = [
            "<div ",
            "style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
            "class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
            "Success: Book was created.",
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
            "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
            "</button>",
            "</div>",
            "<script>",
            "$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
            "<\/script>"
          ].join("");

          // modal form
          function createPermisoAsyncModalForm() {
            $("#create-book-async").modalForm({
                formURL: "{% url 'newnew' tpermiso=1 %}",
                modalID: "#create-modal",
                asyncUpdate: true,
                asyncSettings: {
                  closeOnSubmit: true,
                  successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageCreate,
                  dataUrl: "homeAgente3/",
                  dataElementId: "#permisos-table",
                  dataKey: "table",
                  addModalFormFunction: reinstantiateModalForms
                }
            });
          }
          createPermisoAsyncModalForm();

          // Update book asynchronous button
          // message
          var asyncSuccessMessageUpdate = [
            "<div ",
            "style='position:fixed;top:0;z-index:10000;width:100%;border-radius:0;' ",
            "class='alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0' role='alert'>",
            "Success: Book was updated.",
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>",
            "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>",
            "</button>",
            "</div>",
            "<script>",
            "$('.alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {$('.alert').slideUp(500).remove();});",
            "<\/script>"
          ].join("");

          // modal form
          function updatePermisoModalForm() {
            $(".update-permiso").each(function () {
              $(this).modalForm({
                formURL: $(this).data("form-url"),
                asyncUpdate: true,
                asyncSettings: {
                  closeOnSubmit: false,
                  successMessage: asyncSuccessMessageUpdate,
                  dataUrl: "homeAgente3/",
                  dataElementId: "#books-table",
                  dataKey: "table",
                  addModalFormFunction: reinstantiateModalForms
                }
              });
            });
          }
          updatePermisoModalForm();

          // Delete book buttons - formURL is retrieved from the data of the element
          function deletePermisoModalForm() {
            $(".delete-permiso").each(function () {
                $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data("form-url"), isDeleteForm: true});
            });
          }
          deletePermisoModalForm();

          // Read book buttons
          function readPermisoModalForm() {
            $(".read-permiso").each(function () {
                $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data("form-url")});
            });
          }
          readPermisoModalForm();

          function reinstantiateModalForms() {
            createPermisoAsyncModalForm();
            readPermisoModalForm();
            updatePermisoModalForm();
            deletePermisoModalForm();
          }

          // Filter books button
          $("#filter-book").each(function () {
              $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data("form-url")});
          });

          // Hide message
          $(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
              $(".alert").slideUp(500);
          });
      });
  </script>
  {% endblock body_script %}
```

Aquí debajo, los includes de html: _modal.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="create-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog mt-5">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog mt-5" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y _permisos_table.html

```
<table id="permisos-table" class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">#</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Fecha</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Tipo Permiso</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Motivo</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Estado</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Read / Update / Delete</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for book in permisos %}
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" scope="row">{{ book.perIdpermiso }}</th>
      <td class="text-center">{{ book.perFechaHora }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ book.perTPermiso }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ book.perMotivo }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ book.perEstado }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <!-- Read book buttons -->
        <button type="button" class="read-permiso btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-form-url="{% url 'permiso_ver' pk=book.perIdpermiso tpermiso=book.perTPermiso.tperId %}">
          <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Update book buttons -->
        <button type="button" class="update-permiso btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-form-url="{% url 'permiso_edit' pk=book.perIdpermiso tpermiso=book.perTPermiso.tperId %}">
          <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Delete book buttons -->
        <button type="button" class="delete-permiso btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-form-url="{% url 'permiso_delete' pk=book.perIdpermiso tpermiso=book.perTPermiso.tperId %}">
          <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Para este código, me basé en el ejemplo que está [aquí](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/)

Acompaño unas imágenes:

[image: Modal con validación simple] [image: Cuando genero el error con ValidationError]

Desde ya, muchas gracias por sus orientaciones.